# Export a loop in Python to Excel

Tags: python

I am starting with Python and I am running into difficulty. I am trying to pass the result of a loop in Python to a specific sheet and column of an Excel file.

I am doing it with XlsWriter but it doesn't work. For example, if you want to pass the result of this loop of random numbers, what is wrong with this code?

Example:

```
import xlsxwriter  
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\ej.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Hoja1")
worksheet.write('A1', 'NUMEROS')
from random import seed
from random import random
seed(1)
row =0
for _ in range(5):
    value = random()
    worksheet.write(row, 1, value)
    row += 1    
    print(value)
```

Sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close it.

```
import xlsxwriter  
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\Users\Me\Downloads\ej.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Hoja1")
worksheet.write('A1', 'NUMEROS')
from random import seed
from random import random
seed(1)
row =0
for _ in range(5):
    value = random()
    worksheet.write(row, 1, value)
    row += 1    
    print(value)

workbook.close()
```